# Add regex matches to bidimensional array on behalf of their position

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I'm trying to match the following pattern and create an array as described below:

- `letter 'c' followed by digit`
- `letter 'c' followed by digit dash digit`
- `digit may be followed by an other digit enclosed in square parentheses []`

Patterns are separated by comma.

Example:

```
c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]
```

These numbers are references to paragraphs of articles of laws and where there is a dash it means that's a range of paragraphs.

So for example:

```
c3-5 = paragraphs from 3 to 5
```

With the following regex I can match and separate the numbers:

```
(\d+(\[\d+\])?-\d+(\[\d+\])?)|(\d+(\[\d+\])?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iQ2pQ3/1

But to use effectively these numbers I'm trying to build - without success - an array with the following structure:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [start] => 2
        [end]=> 
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [start] => 3
        [end] => 5
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [start] => 6[2]
        [end] =>
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [start] => 8[4]
        [end] => 10
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [start] => 14
        [end] => 21[5]
    )
)
```

You may see that single matches are added to the array with the key `[start]`, when there's a dash (a range) the first digit is added with the key `[start]` and the second with the key `[end]`.

The only way I thought I could work it out it to first `explode` the string by *comma* and then use a regex on the single exploded strings. Even thought don't know how to build an array as the above one.

Is there a better (more compact and elegant) way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex based solution (see [demo](https://ideone.com/ui4XIX)):

```
$re = '~c(?<start>\d+(?:\[\d+])?)(?:-(?<end>(?&start)?))?~'; 
$str = "c2,c3-5,c6[2],c8[4]-10,c14-21[5]"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$res = array_map(function($ms, $me) { 
    return array("start" => $ms, "end" => $me);
}, $matches["start"], $matches["end"]);
print_r($res);
```

The regex is similar to anubhava's but I shortened it with the help of a named subroutine call (that actually recurses, resuses, the `start` subpattern):

```
c(?<start>\d+(?:\[\d+])?)(?:-(?<end>(?&start)?))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX3iA2/1), here is its explanation:

- `c` - a literal `c`
- `(?<start>\d+(?:\[\d+])?)` - (Group named "start") an obligatory subpattern, `\d+` matches 1+ digits that are optionally followed with 1 occurrence of `:` followed with `[` + digits + `]`
- `(?:-(?<end>(?&start)?))?` - 1 or 0 (optional) sequence of `-` followed with the "start" group (the value is placed into the "end" group).

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't know that groups could be named. Very good and useful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your regex to this to capture empty matches as well:

```
c(?P<start>\d+(?:\[\d+\])?)-?(?P<end>\d+(?:\[\d+\])?|)(?=,|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ2pQ3/2)

`(?P<end>\d+(?:\[\d+\])?|)` ensures we also capture empty matches in `end` group.